# Sphincs+ in Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I was trying to understand how to use Sphincs+.

```
package cdss;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.crypto.sphincsplus.SPHINCSPlusKeyGenerationParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.crypto.sphincsplus.SPHINCSPlusKeyPairGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.crypto.sphincsplus.SPHINCSPlusParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.crypto.sphincsplus.SPHINCSPlusPublicKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;

public class Sphincs3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Generate a SPHINCS+ key pair
        
        SPHINCSPlusKeyPairGenerator keyGen = new SPHINCSPlusKeyPairGenerator();
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        SPHINCSPlusKeyGenerationParameters params = new SPHINCSPlusKeyGenerationParameters(random,
                SPHINCSPlusParameters.sha2_128s_simple);
        keyGen.init(params);
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        SPHINCSPlusPublicKeyParameters publicKeyParams = (SPHINCSPlusPublicKeyParameters) pair.getPublic();
        
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKeyParams.getEncoded();

        SPHINCSPlusPublicKeyParameters pasd = new SPHINCSPlusPublicKeyParameters(SPHINCSPlusParameters.sha2_128s_simple, 
                publicKeyBytes);

    }
}
```

And I was trying to rebiuld my publicKey from the encoded. However, when I complied, it said: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: public key encoding does not match parameters
at org.bouncycastle.pqc.crypto.sphincsplus.SPHINCSPlusPublicKeyParameters.(SPHINCSPlusPublicKeyParameters.java:17)
at cdss.Sphincs3.main(Sphincs3.java:26)"

I wonder why it is the problem?

Comment: You need to rebuild the keys using the **KeyFactory** and - depending on key type - use an **EncodedKeySpec** as parameter ("PKCS8EncodedKeySpec" for private and "X509EncodedKeySpec" for public keys)

Comment: @MichaelFehr hey I tried to use KeyFactoryInfo as well, but it said it could not recognize either.

Comment: I did not mention **KeyFactoryInfo** but **KeyFactory** and in my case I'm been able to "recover" the original private and public keys from encoded form.

Comment: @MichaelFehr Hey i am using Bouncy Castle so I looked into PublicKeyFactory in the package, and it requires KeyFactoryInfo, which I am stucking right now. I am not sure your about your approach. Are you working on sphincs+ too? Could you please show me an example of the code?

Comment: Lack of OIDs for the 'simple' parameters [was a bug fixed in July and released in 1.76](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/commit/f9dd36feb210ad682e11aef052a08cc99479176d)

Answer (score 0):

This is a cutout from a larger project where I'm generating a Spincs Plus keypair, store them in byte array encoding, restore the keys, sign a message and verify the signature. I left all imports although not needed for the following code.

```
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastlePQCProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.pqc.jcajce.spec.SPHINCSPlusParameterSpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
```

Load the key:

```
PublicKey publicKeySphincsPlusLoad = getSphincsPlusPublicKeyFromEncoded(publicKeySphincsPlusByte);
```

Verify the signature:

```
boolean signatureVerified = pqcSphincsPlusVerification(publicKeySphincsPlusLoad, dataToSign, signature);
```

Code:

```
private static PublicKey getSphincsPlusPublicKeyFromEncoded(byte[] encodedKey) {
    X509EncodedKeySpec x509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
    try {
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("SPHINCSPlus", "BCPQC");
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(x509EncodedKeySpec);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private static boolean pqcSphincsPlusVerification(PublicKey publicKey, byte[] dataToSign, byte[] signature) {
    try {
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SPHINCSPlus", "BCPQC");
        sig.initVerify((PublicKey) publicKey);
        sig.update(dataToSign, 0, dataToSign.length);
        return sig.verify(signature);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidKeyException | SignatureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I see your approach of creating keys by using JCA but with a "BCPQC" provider. However, in my project, I tended to use packages in Bouncy Castle directly and create the key without using JCA features. But thanks a lot and appreciate!

Comment: @Alex: did you see the tests where a rebuild of keys is shown using KeyFactoryInfo: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/main/core/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/pqc/crypto/test/SphincsPlusTest.java ?

Comment: Thanks for providing that and I have looked it through. I noticed that they define the parameters as " parameters = (SPHINCSPlusParameters)SPHINCSPlusParameters.class.getField(b.toString()).get(null);", but I don't think we should do this when we want to use the sphincs+ package and define the parameters. Therefore, my concern is still why it cannot recoginize parameters created by this way "SPHINCSPlusParameters.sha2_128s_simple".